# Accessing properties of QML objects from C++ withoun Q_PROPERTY definition

Tags: qt4, qml, qt-quick

I know, it's possible to define a QObject with custom properties and expose this object in QML environment. But this way, for each new property I'd need to recompile C++ code.

Is it possible, to make a dynamic binding from C++/Qt to QML-objects?
Something like:

```
//C++ code: 
updateProperty("myQmlObject.any_property", "Hello World");
```

Thank you!

**SOLVED:**

```
_view->rootContext()->setContextProperty( "cppmessage" , "Hello from C++" );
```

WHERE: *view* is a QDeclarativeView, and *cppmessage* is used in QML without prior declaration like: "text: cppmessage"

This link was usefull for finding the solution: http://xizhizhu.blogspot.com/2010/10/hybrid-application-using-qml-and-qt-c.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, This can be done. [Link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtbinding.html#modifying-properties)

```
// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    property int someNumber: 100
}

//C++
QDeclarativeEngine engine;
QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();

qDebug() << "Property value:" << QDeclarativeProperty::read(object,"someNumber").toInt();
QDeclarativeProperty::write(object, "someNumber", 5000);

qDebug() << "Property value:" << object->property("someNumber").toInt();
object->setProperty("someNumber", 100);
```

Edit:1
Another way to do it , as suggested by @Valentin is listed here
[link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativecontext.html#details)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. hover I found out, it seems to be quiet easy: setContextProperty. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I guess that is another way to do it as well, i will add that to the answer.